# mongodb instantly stopping after starting

Tags: mongodb, terminal

A fairly simple question...

mongod in the command line just stopped working?

In the command line i start up mongod like i used to and it doesn't start and just goes straight back to the command line:

```
username:~ computer$ mongod
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
username:~ computer$
```

Tried in terminal mongod --repair and nothing happens... it just waits longer before going back to the normal username:~ computer$

Why is this broken now?... how do i figure out what went wrong? So confused.

I'm trying to uninstall mongodb and re-install... even that is hard... how to you uninstall it in terminal?

ER

Answer (score 0):

This cmd seems to have fixed it:

$ mongod --repairpath arg

Answer (score 0):

For start [mongod](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) you need parameter `-dbpath` `-logpath` mandatorily or configure all parameters in `/etc/mongod.conf` and run with `root` user

If you run `mongo` shell, in console typing `mongo`, not `mongod`, `mongod` launch `mongo` process, `mongo` is for access to shell.

If you need unistall mongo, only need delete all mongo files in `/user/bin` or path where unzipped the pack mongo